# Odoo15 - Delivery Slip report can't be translated

Tags: odoo, translate, odoo-15

Issue: Delivery Slip PDF report can't be translated when the language changed

Reproduce Step: Inventory-> Delivery Order -> click into one record -> print-> delivery slip -> change user profile languare and try to download report again.
[image]

note: the picking operation PDF report can be translated as expected when change user language

Any idea? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Odoo translation done based on the customer language I have attached image with customer language German in delivery slip report.

[image]

And if you want to change it as per user language you can update it on delivery slip report.

```
 <t t-call="stock.report_delivery_document" t-lang="o.partner_id.lang"/>
```

from this to update as below

```
 <t t-call="stock.report_delivery_document" t-lang="user.partner_id.lang"/>
```